# I want to assert the url with current url, but not assert the complete url just asserted on page url

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

```
Current_Url = https://Example.com/page_Name?start_date=2023-03-21&end_date=2023-03-21

unique_url_Total_client_ts = "https://Example.com/page_Name"

    assert Form_Data.unique_url_Total_client_ts in driver.current_url
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
    time.sleep(2)
```

**Form_Data is a class where all the URL saved.**

I just want to assert url at Example.com/page_Name, left the url part where data are showing.

It always failed because url assert complete url.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
assert Current_Url.startswith(Form_Data.unique_url_Total_client_ts)
```